# Prove that $\exists k\geq 0$ such that $f^n(0)=0$ for all $n\geq k$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f $be an entire function.Suppose that for each $a\in \Bbb R ,\exists c_n$ in the expansion $ f(z)=\sum c_n(z-a)^n$ for some $n$ such that $c_n=0$.
Then prove that

> $\exists k\geq 0$ such that $f^n(0)=0$ for all $n\geq k$.

Now $c_n=\dfrac{f^n(a)}{n!}$. But it is not helping .Any hint will be highly beneficial.

Comment: I think you have to edit your post, for example what is $c_n\in f(z)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c_n = \frac{f^n (a)}{n!} = 0$ which implies that $f^n (a) = 0$.

Now comes the key to this exercise : there are countably many derivative functions, yet we have an uncountable amount of values for which the derivative functions vanish. This implies that there must exist some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^n (x) = 0$ for $x \in A$ such that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Since $f^n (x) = 0$ for an uncountable amount of distinct points, and an uncountable set of points always has a limit point, then it follows by the identity theorem that $f^n (x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

Since $f^n (x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$ it follows that $f^n (x)$ is a constant function and hence its remaining derivatives all vanish.

When I first saw this exercise quite some time ago, I was rather overwhelmed. I suggest you read through my answer and think deeply about why certain steps are true. In particular I suggest thinking through the uncountability argument used, and pay close attention to the use of the identity theorem  and the way in which its conditions are met.

Comment: If $f^n(x)=0\forall x$ does not it imply that $f^n(x)=0$ you have said it is constant;please check it.Rest is fine;I waiting for your reply to accept it

Comment: The nth derivative function is $0$ for all values in the complex plane, so this makes it constant.